# Создание записей с различным набором атрибутов(2)

Tags: sql, база-данных, ms-access

Имеется 4 типа компаний(дистрибьютер, оптовик, мелкий оптовик, сети), с которыми мы работаем, но набор атрибутов между дистрибьютером, оптовиком, и мелким оптовиком отличается от сетей. Пробовал реализовать данную схему подобным образом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные по дистрибьютерам, оптовикам и мелк. оптовикам вынес в одну таблицу, а данные по сетям вынес в другую. Но связь один к одному требует чтобы одна запись находилась как в "описание_к_компании" так и в "описание_к_сетям". Уважаемые знатоки просьба помочь решить данную задачу!!)

Comment: "...отличается от сетей..." - вы имели ввиду, что для разных компаний будет разное количество атрибутов в "описание_к_сетям"?

Comment: В "описании к сетям" будет одинаковый набор атрибутов. Для разных типов компаний, различны атрибуты. Для дистров,оптовиков,мелких оптовиков один набор атрибутов(описание к компаниям) для сетей другой (описание к сетям)

Comment: Тут или у компании должно быть 4 ссылки на все возможные  `описание_к_*` (можно вынести в отдельную таблицу, которую связать с компаниями), или в каждом `описании_к_*` ссылка на компанию.

Comment: А можно подробнее насчёт "4 ссылки" и в какую таблицу это выносить, если можно, для наглядности, картиночки)

Comment: У каждого `описания_к_*` сделать свой собственный id, в таблице `компании` сделать 4 столбца из которых заполнен будет только один.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените связь между общей таблицей и описаниями на один-ко-многим, оставив уникальный первичный ключ на описаниях. Это решит проблему с отсутствием записей в описаниях, но не позволит создать более одного описания на каждую компанию, т.е. фактическое соотношение будет один-к-одному

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду убрать первичный ключ из таблицы "общая"?

Comment: Ни в коем случае! Нужно поменять тип связей между общей таблицей и описаниями, чтобы около ключа описаний стоял знак бесконечности, а не 1, как сейчас.

Comment: Для этого лучше всего будет добавить собственный первичный ключ к каждой из таблиц описания, можно автоинкремент, снять первичный ключ с существующих полей, по которым идет связь (ID_сети) и добавить уникальный индекс на эти поля